# Simplest survey tool to integrate into a website

Tags: startup, survey, user-feedback

For a startup website. Should have this -

**1.)** What they would like to see/improved upon ? - Users can enter a one liner.
**2.)** Visitors can leave a remark.
**3.)** Consumers can vote on suggestions & hence the top suggestion bubbles up.
**4.)** Allows for anonymous input.

I think I've seen something similar to this, but don't remember where.

Would be good to know what you all use for quick integration.

Comment: startup website .. quick integration into what??

Comment: https://developer.examinare.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked http://getsatisfaction.com/ out?

Comment: Thanks! Trying to find if it allows for anonymous posts.
Let me update my question with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://uk.toluna.com/Default.aspx will answer your needs.